# What the codes on csUserName in IIS Logs means

Tags: iis

When analyzing the IIS Logs, sometimes the csUserName field comes in form of a code, such as lDU9TNFo9/IwGz75KGQn5YB4KJlsX+UamJx11y4M2muiWSWyXCE6vbeQgG1kHXxG

I thought it could be base64 encoding, but I couldn't decode using online tools.

I know the csUserName may point to the user of the web application, I know this may be the SID of a user and sometimes may be the SID of system user accounts, but how to decipher this code?

Answer (score 0):

cs-username means the name of the authenticated user that accessed the server. Anonymous users are indicated by a hyphen. So your csUserName field may be that the user is not authenticated.

[image]

Comment: There is always an authenticated user, the point is if the application is using the end user identity or is using its own identity. On the 2nd case, it's understandable the user name appear as a SID, but this code is not a SID. An hyphen would be understandable as anonymous as well, but this code?

Comment: What is end user identity and own identity? SID is a unique value of variable length that is used to identify a security principal (such as a security group) in Windows operating systems, is it the same as cs-username? and are you sure the above string corresponds to the csUserName field in iis log?

Comment: Yes, the above string is the csUserName in IIS log, no doubt. The user login is a security principal, with a SID. The application login is also a security principal, also with its own SID. Special application logins, such as System Account, are also security principals, as long I know, with SID's.  So, if an application access IIS there is a security principal. user without authentication would be a dash "-", that's why I think these codes means special security principals, but I can't translate them

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen such a csUserName field, but  as far as I know, there is a tool called [Log Parser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) that can change its format, but I'm not sure if it will work for you. you can give it a try, hope this helps you.